# UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on input

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having a specific problem coding my first Selenium Project. I have already read other posts about this error, but could not get an answer.

I am trying to scrap this webpage: https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices

This is my code:

```
!pip install webdriver-manager
!pip install pandas
conda install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

website = 'https://www.interpol.int/How-we-work/Notices/Red-Notices/View-Red-Notices'
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()

search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//i[@class='privacy-cookie-banner__icon-close']")
search_button.click()

name = []
ages = []
country = []

for age in range(18,100):

    min_age = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMin"]')) # Preencher idade minima
    min_age.click()
    min_age.select_by_value(age)
    #min_age.send_keys(age)
    
    max_age = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMax"]')) # Preencher idade máxima
    max_age.click()
    max_age.select_by_value(age)
    #max_age.send_keys(age)

    search_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//button[@id='submit' and @type='submit']")
    search_button.click()


    # Localiza o elemento da barra de paginação usando XPath
    pagination = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@id, "paginationPanel")]')

    # Localiza todos os elementos <li> dentro do elemento de paginação
    pages = pagination.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//li')

    # Obtenha o número da primeira e última página
    initial_page = 1
    last_page = int(pages[-2].text)


    # The while loop below will work until the the bot reaches the last page of the website, then it will break
    while initial_page <= last_page:
        time.sleep(6)  # let the page render correctly

         # Explicit Wait
        container = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__list")]')))
        products = WebDriverWait(container, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__item notice_red")]')))

        #container = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__list")]')
        #products = container.find_elements(by='xpath', value='.//div[contains(@class, "redNoticesList__item notice_red")]')

        for product in products:
            name.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value=".//div[@class='redNoticeItem__labelText']").text)
            ages.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="age"]').text)
            country.append(product.find_element(by='xpath', value='.//span[@class="nationalities"]').text)

            # locate and click on a button
        try:
            next_button = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value="//a[@class='nextIndex right-arrow']")
            next_button.click()
        except:
            pass


        initial_page = initial_page + 1
        
driver.quit()
```

I am trying to build a loop throw the min and max ages, but the error on the title of this post appears.

The loop mentioned is:

```
for age in range(18,100):

    min_age = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMin"]')) # Preencher idade minima
    min_age.click()
    min_age.select_by_value(age)
    #min_age.send_keys(age)
    
    max_age = Select(driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMax"]')) # Preencher idade máxima
    max_age.click()
    max_age.select_by_value(age)
    #max_age.send_keys(age)
```

May someone explain to me what do to, please?

I have tried different Selenium aproaches, verified posts here on StackOverflow and asked ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause of the Issue:** As the error message rightly says, `Select` class works only on `<select>` node. But you are trying to use it on `<input>` node. Hence the error.

**Solution:** Remove the `Select` class from your code and use `send_keys()` to enter the value into the field. See the code below:

```
min_age = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMin"]')  # Preencher idade minima
min_age.send_keys(age)

max_age = driver.find_element(by='xpath', value='//input[@id="ageMax"]')  # Preencher idade máxima
max_age.send_keys(age)
```